# Does selling with your pet net you as much money as you would've got by selling in person?

Tags: torchlight

Selling items with your pet is a very handy feature, but does it net me as much money as I would've gotten had I used a town portal scroll and sold it myself?

Comment: Yes. I don't have a reference though, sorry.

Answer (score 23):

I met my first underground merchant, which makes it easy to address this question with science. This is what I had in my pet's inventory.

[image]

The salesman [offered](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvvihYwat4zDdDZ1NWhhSWlycDZWczhlZ2FuWVJnU1E#gid=0) a total of 1,039 gold for these items. And well, ...

[image]

It appears **there is no penalty for selling items through your pet.**

Comment: Cool, +1 for science.

Comment: The question now is: "Is the traveling merchant prices are better than going to town?" - Edit: I made the test and it's the same :)